# Bean of type 'com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I encountered a problem with my Ribbon application. Here is my code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
@RibbonClient(name= "bye", configuration=RibbonConfig.class )
public class RibbonAppApplication {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RibbonAppApplication.class, args);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public String getService() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://bye",String.class);
    }
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

And my `RibbonConfig.class`:

```java
@Configuration
public class RibbonConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
        return new PingUrl(false,"/health");
    }
  
    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }
}
```

However, I got the following error:

> Parameter 0 of method ribbonPing in practice.zuul.zach.ribbonapp.RibbonConfig required a bean of type 'com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig' in your configuration.

Is there any ways to solve it?

Comment: Autowire the IClientConfig.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! May I ask how to autowired the IClientConfig? it was a parameter

Comment: @Autowired
 IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig; still same error

Comment: @JaisAnkit here passing as argument and autowiring in the class is the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved when i add this line in RibbonAppApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig"})
```

Comment: but if you do this. it will exclude your ribbonclientconfig implementation

Comment: This answer is wrong. IClientConfig is an interface!